# F# Seq.choose() Error FS0001

Tags: f#, match, sequence, msdn

I have tried MSDN's [example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/seq.choose%5B't,'u%5D-function-%5Bfsharp%5D) for the Seq.choose function (written below) in both a .fsx file and the interactive window for Visual Studio, but it repeatedly returns an error FS0001, stating that the "None" option is a PageExt type rather than the abstract option type 'a option.

I have searched in vain for an explanation of the PageExt type or why this could be returning an error when the None keyword should just represent the "no value" option in the match expression.

```
let numbers = seq {1..20}
let evens = Seq.choose(fun x -> 
                               match x with
                               | x when x%2=0 -> Some(x)
                               | _ -> None ) numbers
printfn "numbers = %A\n" numbers
printfn "evens = %A" evens
;;

                                  | _ -> None ) numbers
  ---------------------------------------^^^^
> 

C:Path\stdin(38,40): error FS0001: This expression was expected to have type
    'a option    
but here has type
    PageExt
```

Thanks for any help anyone can offer!

Comment: This sounds very much like you have a type defined called `PageExt`, where one union case is called `None`. Right-click into your interactive window, click "Reset session"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `PageExt` type is likely something that you've pulled into your current FSI session previously which bound something to `None`, essentially blocking FSI from recognizing the normal option types.

In F#, you can reuse names, which "shadows" the original value.  For example, in FSI, if you type:

```
let a = 1;;
let a = 2.3;;
a;;
```

You'll notice that it shows:

```
val a : int = 1
```

Then

```
val a : float = 2.3
```

Finally

```
val it : float = 2.3
```

This isn't changing the definition of `a`, but rather defining a new `a` name that shadows (or "hides") the original bound value.

In your case, you have a `None` name that's bound to something with a `PageExt` type that's shadowing Option.None, preventing it from being usable.

The easiest way to fix this is to reset your FSI session.  Right click in the F# Interactive window, and choose "Reset iteractive session".  If you do that, then run the code you pasted, it will work fine.

Comment: Right on target. Thank you!